# asp.net core share remote or use common wwwroot among apps running behind the load balancer

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, load-balancing, f5, wwwroot

I have a scenario where I'm using 2 IIS servers running on asp.net core (nopcommerce 4.10) behind the load balancer F5 with sticky session.

Since the nopcommerce doesn't support web farm at the moment, I'm looking for a work around to share the wwwroot folder between these two servers for the images/file and pondering if it's possible to create wwwroot folder somewhere else than app root path so that these 2 app can use it (which is possible if somehow I configure dotnet core app in startup.cs to use wwwroot folder from different path). 
Or alternatively share the wwwroot folder for both from one of these.

My current solution is to copy the file on another server when anything uploaded from admin side but this won't work with bundling.

Comment: you could try to use a network share folder and then mount the shared folder to the IIS server by using a virtual path to achieve this requirement.

Comment: @jalpa trying that, will let you know if it works

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment and answer from Robban1980 helped and I really appreciate it. Although I'm posting my final solution hoping, it will help someone,  specifically for nopcommerce developer.

I have override the method for the in FileProvider (nopcommerce uses it for accessing file resources) to take files from my folder instead of taking it from wwwroot.

```
public override string GetAbsolutePath(params string[] paths)  
{
      var allPaths = paths.ToList();
      allPaths.Insert(0, "my-folder");
      return Path.Combine(allPaths.ToArray());
}
```

Also, I had to set read/write file permission to the folder to make it accessible via a network

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nopcommerce, but one way could be to setup a network share and map it in to the wwwroot folder and give write permission on it to the application pools. The write permission is just because you wrote that you are uploading files from Admin. I guess you also have things part of the bundling that you want to include in the wwwroot folder?

Like wwwroot/my_upload_folder_share

Comment: I think you didn't get the problem, I already have image upload and bundle inside the www root. Also app pool has full permission, the problem is that how can I share it between the two servers

Comment: That's the potential problem the network share mapped as a folder in wwwroot on the servers would solve. just set it up as part of the deployment.